# Join two tables, not joined with any foreign keys and different unrelated ids

Tags: sql, postgresql, join

I have two tables.

```
CompanyNames:
company_name text (Unique)
companyname_id bigint 

HomeNickNames:
home_nickname text (Unique)
nickname_id bigint
```

So, the rows will be like:

```
    CompanyNames
    ==============
    company_name   ||   companyname_id
|:--------------------------------------:|
     Robert         |      123
     Mr.Robert      |      123
     Mr.RobertGrant |      123



    HomeNiceNames
    ==============
    home_nickname  ||   nickname_id
|:-------------------------------------:|
     Robert         |      431
     Robb           |      431
     DearRobb       |      431
```

Assume almost every company name and nickname can be joined because of one same company name and nickname.

I need a query that can generate the following result:

```
       name_id || home_nickname
|:-----------------------------------:|
       123     |   Robb
       123     |   Robert
       123     |   DearRobb
```

Comment: Postgres. But, any database is fine.

Comment: Can you post your query

Comment: once you figure out how to give PG artificial intelligence so it can figure out that "Robb" and "Robert" are the same name, then the join itself should be utterly trivial...

Comment: If this were my project, I would need some solid criteria for what constitutes a match.

Comment: In my case, names are all unique. If for a particular person, a company name and nickname don't match at all, I wouldn't want it in the result. That's not an issue I am looking to tackle.

Comment: What does "don't match at all" mean? What does "matches just enough" mean?

Comment: I mean like Robb and Robert don't match at all. Robert and Robert match completely. So, since Robert and Robert matched completely, I need to take the home_nickname id of Robert and join it with the company_id of Robert. So, now I want to join all nicknames with the nickname_id I have, to company_id.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Find `Robert`first and then all nicks with that id:

```
select 
   c.companyname_id
  ,n2.home_nickname
from CompanyNames as c
join HomeNiceNames as n
  on c.company_name = n.home_nickname -- match Robert
join HomeNiceNames as n2
  on n.nickname_id = n2.nickname_id   -- match nickname with same id as Robert
```

Comment: your solution is even better than mine :-)

Answer (score 1):

Still not sure what are you looking for. But just my guess:

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/a2f0a/2

```
SELECT t.companyname_id, t2.home_nickname
FROM (SELECT companyname_id, GROUP_CONCAT(company_name) names
FROM CompanyNames
GROUP BY companyname_id) t
LEFT JOIN HomeNiceNames
ON FIND_IN_SET(HomeNiceNames.home_nickname, t.names)
LEFT JOIN HomeNiceNames t2
ON HomeNiceNames.nickname_id = t2.nickname_id
```